# Ruby on Rails - link_to with tag filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On Rails 4. I am making a site with products. These products can have many tags. Models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, through: :product_tags

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, through: :product_tags
```

I am trying to make an application-wide navbar where a user can click each navigation link to take him/her to the product index, and the products will be filtered according to the tag name from the link. So far I actually have this working:

```
application.html.erb

<li><%= link_to "Pencils", products_path(tag: "Pencils") %></li>


products_controller.rb

def index
    if params[:tag]
      @products = Product.joins(:tags).order('id').page(params[:page]).per(20).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] })
    else
      @products = @q.result(distinct: true).order('id').page(params[:page]).per(20)
    end

  end
```

(The "else" part is using Ransack, there is also a form inside the header to input search terms if you don't want to use the navigation links).

My trouble comes when **I want to return products that have TWO tags I want to filter for.** For example, let's say I have the tags "Blue" and "Pencils" and I wanted to make a link_to that finds all Blue Pencil products. I tried a few things, including experimenting with .split() but couldn't get the result I needed. Don't want to use a gem here if there is another way. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass two tags...

```
<li><%= link_to "Blue Pencils", products_path(tag: "Pencils", tag2: "Blue") %></li>
```

... and then you should be able to use multiple `where` clauses ...

```
def index#
  if params[:tag2]
    @products = Product.joins(:tags).order('id').page(params[:page]).per(20).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] }).where(tags: { name: params[:tag2] })
  elsif params[:tag]
    @products = Product.joins(:tags).order('id').page(params[:page]).per(20).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] })
  else
    @products = @q.result(distinct: true).order('id').page(params[:page]).per(20)
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a good thought, didn't think about two different where clauses. This is not working however, it returns nothing when I try it (no error, just doesn't have any products listed)...not sure why...will keep trying a few things.

Comment: Yes, right, I think it won't work... could you try with `includes` instead of `joins`?  ...  I thin the joins does lazy loading of only the matching tag record, but includes should include all tag records.  Or I could just be talking through my hat...

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help me! Trying "includes" did not work either...must be missing a piece of the puzzle yet.